# Add subscriber to my mailchimp subscriber list

Tags: node.js, express, mailchimp

I am new to backend web development and trying to create subscriber through a sign up page and add them to my Mailchimp through API but I am not been able to create subscriber (subscribers are not adding in my Mailchimp audience list). Below is my code.

```
 const port = 3000;
    
    const https = require('node:https');
    
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    }));
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html")
    });
    
    app.post('/', (req, res) => {
      const email = req.body.emailId;
      const firstName = req.body.firstName;
      const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    
      var data = {
        members: [{
          email_address: email,
          status: "Subscribed",
          merge_fields: {
            FNAME: firstName,
            LNAME: lastName
          }
        }]
      };
    
      const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    
      const url = "https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/"list_id"/";
      const options = {
        method: "POST",
        auth: "dALamyan:apiKey"
      };
    
      const request = https.request(url, options, (response) => {
        response.on("data", (data) => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
      });
      request.write(jsonData);
      request.end;
    });
    
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log("app listening on port 3000.");
    });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my code below. It's working fine for me.
Change **X** in the API endpoint, **listID** and **apiKey** as per your account settings.

Cheers.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const firstName = req.body.firstname;
    const lastName = req.body.lastname;
    const email = req.body.email;

    const data = {
        members: [{
                email_address: email,
                status: "subscribed",
                merge_fields: {
                    FNAME: firstName,
                    LNAME: lastName
                } 
            }]
    };

    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    const url = "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + listID;
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        auth: "archit:apiKey"
    }

    const request =  https.request(url, options, (response) => {
        response.on("data", (data) => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });

    request.write(jsonData);
    request.end();
});

app.listen("3000", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000.");
});
```